# No route matches {:action=>"destroy"　のエラーが解決しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

下記のエラーが出たので、調べてpathに引数を渡してみたのですがエラーが解決しません。
何か他に改善策はありますでしょうか。

#### エラーの内容

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Circles#show

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :circle_id=>"5", :controller=>"circle_users", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

<%= link_to '退会する', circle_circle_user_path(@circle, @circle_user), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: "サークル「#{@circle.name}」を退会します。よろしいですか？" } ,class:"btn btn-warning btn-lg" %>
    
・・・
```

```
route

circle_circle_user DELETE /circles/:circle_id/circle_users/:id(.:format)                                           circle_users#destroy
```

**/app/views/circles/show.html.erb**

```
<% if @circle.circle_user?(current_user) %>
    <%= link_to '退会する', circle_circle_user_path(@circle, @circle_user), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: "サークル「#{@circle.name}」を退会します。よろしいですか？" } ,class:"btn btn-warning btn-lg" %>
<!--サークルには所属していないが、ログインはしている場合 -->
<% elsif current_user %>
    <% if @apply %>
        <%= link_to '申請取消', circle_apply_path(@circle, @apply), method: :delete, class:"btn btn-warning btn-lg" %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to '加入申請', circle_applies_path(@circle), method: :post, class:"btn btn-warning btn-lg" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**/app/controllers/circles_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @circle = Circle.find(params[:id])
  @circleposts = @circle.circleposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @circleposts = Circlepost.where(circle_id: @circle.id).all
end
```

Comment: ちなみに@circle_user = CircleUser.find(params[:id])をshowアクションに入れたら、Couldn't find CircleUser with 'id'=1というエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: 削除はされているとのことですが、どうしたらこのエラーは消えるのでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

退会ということはユーザはログインしてる current_user 固定なんですよね？

```
resources :circles do
  delete 'leave', on: :member
end
```

とか circle が主語となるアクションを追加して

```
<%= link_to '退会する', leave_circle_path(@circle), method: :delete ...
```

でいいのではないですか？

そうするとクリックした時に Circles#leave にとんできて
削除するユーザは current_user で取得して削除処理すればいいので
ユーザはパラメータで渡す必要はないと思います